# No such column error message

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I read the tutorial from the django site and now I hit the wall. It seems very simple but it is giving me a problem. Everytime I run populate_rango.py script I get an error.

I have modified my script and my models.py file based on the example from Tango with Django site but still getting this not creating one of the column.

error :

```
    Starting Rango population script...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_rango.py", line 67, in <module>
    populate()
  File "populate_rango.py", line 8, in populate
    url="http://www.google.com")
  File "populate_rango.py", line 55, in add_page
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, likes=likes, views=views)[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 304, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
   self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
   six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-         packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 451, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: rango_page.likes
```

populate_rango.py

```
import os
def populate():
    search_cat = add_cat('Search Engins')

    add_page(cat=search_cat,
        title="Google",
        url="http://www.google.com")

     add_page(cat=search_cat,
        title="Yahoo !",
        url="http://www.yahoo.com")

    add_page(cat=search_cat,
        title="Bing",
        url="http://www.bing.com")

    social_cat = add_cat("Social Media")

    add_page(cat=social_cat,
        title="Facebook",
        url="http://www.facebook.com")

    add_page(cat=social_cat,
        title="LinkedIn",
        url="http://www.linkedin.com")     

    add_page(cat=social_cat,
        title="Twitter",
        url="http://www.twitter.com/")

    news_cat = add_cat("News Sites")

    add_page(cat=news_cat,
        title="CNN",
        url="http://www.cnn.com/")

    comme_cat = add_cat("Commerce")     

    add_page(cat=comme_cat,
        title="Amazon",
        url="http://www.amazon.com")

    add_page(cat=comme_cat,
        title="eBay",
        url="http://www.ebay.com")

    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0, likes=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, likes=likes, views=views)[0]
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    return c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Rango population script..."
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tangorango.settings')
    from rango.models import Category, Page
    populate()
```

modes.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)    
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py syncdb` after extending the models?

Comment: @TimZimmermann yes I did. I generated the sql tables and it shows when i run python manage.py sql rango but when the script runs i get the error

Comment: Did you check whether the column exists in the DB?

Comment: how do I do that. I ran "python manage.py sql rango and it shows there. is there another way to check

Comment: `python manage.py sql` just produces the SQL statements, it does not execute those statements and thus does not alter the database schema. How you can check whether the column exists depends on which database you use.

Comment: can you tell me how if I am using sqlite3

Comment: Use `python manage.py dbshell` to connect to your DB. Then enter `PRAGMA table_info(rango_page)` and see if the column is there.

Comment: @timzimmermann ok thank you now I am getting somewhere. It is not showing links even though I have defined it. Can I added manually? Also,, why can I see it when I run python manage.py sqlall rango but not when i run your command

Answer (score 2):

run this command :

```
python manage.py sqlall <your_app>
```

see the result , then if there wasn't `likes` table among them run this command and add it manually :

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

you can add it with this code:

```
ALTER TABLE "Page" ADD COLUMN "likes" IntegerField(0)
```

**but note that sync db doesn't make integrate schema changes once the tables are created. You have to delete the database manually and do syncdb again.** 
for more information read [THIS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) recipe of `syncdb` in django site !

Comment: thank you for your reply. I checked and likes is listed, but my script doesnt see it.

Comment: well com so i suggest if its possible for you delete you database and crate and sync again.